# Leave application running as we switch users

Tags: users, services

How can I leave Deluge Bittorrent running as different family members log into and use our Ubuntu 12.04 laptop?

This seems like it should be some sort of daemon, but of course it has a GUI, which I'd like users to have equal access to.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the *switch user* feature, the programs in your session continue running (and your torrents will continue downloading/seeding)

But maybe what you're after is transmission-daemon

Comment: Deluge also works as transmission, using the client-server architecture that is a daemon with a variety of UIs that can connect to. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, the Switch User feature is good. How can I guarantee that Deluge starts up when the computer does, regardless of which  user  starts up the machine and logs in?